# Add class to image in WYSISWG editor (Advanced Custom Fields / WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I want to add a class to every image which I post in a WYSISWG editor field of Advanced Custom Fields. Every image should have the class `img-fluid` in addition to the other editor classes.

I've managed to add the class if I add the image in the normal WordPress editor. This is code in my `functions.php`:

```
/* Add img-fluid to images in the_content */
function add_image_responsive_class($content) {
   global $post;
   $pattern ="/<img(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/i";
   $replacement = '<img$1class="$2 img-fluid"$3>';
   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_image_responsive_class');
```

But that code doesn't work for the WYSISWG editor field of Advanced Custom Fields.
Is there any other way to adress the image in the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also launch your action with the filter **acf_the_content** and it should work fine (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wysiwyg-editor/)